# How to pass the foreign key

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to the mvc and asp.net and facing the following problem.
I have an index that list all the cars I have in my database, in the action columns which includes Edit, Details, Delete I added book trip to create the trip.

in the book trip link I want to pass the id of the car:
my way which is totally wrong is this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Create", "Trips", new { id= item.Id })" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
    <i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

because in this way the controller will understand that this id is the Trip Id not the Car Id.

**Also, I do both create and edit at the same page**

I have the trip id and car id hidden in the top of the form like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CarId)
```

My question is: Is there is a way that let me pass the Car Id and the controller won't think its the Trip Id?

hope you understand my question

Comment: The controller doesn't "Think" anything. It simply accepts a parameter that you have defined. What you then do with that id is up to you. If the Car Id is in your model, i.e. item.CarID, then add that as the parameter.

Comment: In your controller method add a new parameter carId (if using viewmodel add a new property in view model) and from view pass { carID=item.Id }

Answer (score 1):

If your controller action is like (you are using routing)

```
[route("trip/{id}/{isCarid"]
public Actionresult Edit(int id,bool isCarid=false)
{

}
```

then
    @{bool isCarid=true;}

```
<a href="/yourcontrollername/trip/@item.id/@isCarid" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">
<i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

or if

```
public Actionresult Trip(int id,bool isCarid=false)
{

}
```

then
  @{ bool isCarid=true;}

Comment: At the moment I am creating the trip, so it doesn't have an Id .. the Id i am passing is for the car

Comment: I have added more explanation to the the problem it might be clear now.

Comment: but you were asking how to pass forign key

Comment: To add a trip the car has the foreign key

Comment: check the answer now you can set the bool value which will decide if it is a car id or not

Comment: Thank you, I have solved it .. my controller was checking the id and i had to change it.